# Why matlab execution time differs when pressing F9

Tags: matlab, time

I have a pretty simple situation where matlab execution time differs depending on the way I run the code :

```
tic
pause(1)
toc
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a script, I get something like :

```
Elapsed time is 1.000241 seconds.
```

If I select the code and press <kbd>F9</kbd>, I get something like :

```
Elapsed time is 1.025203 seconds
```

I notice a 25ms time difference which is reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

if you copy and past your code in Matlab "Command Window" you see big difference as compare running your code as a m file.

on my computer (Intel i7, 16GB RAM), my result is varying +/- 5ms.

```
Elapsed time is 1.002843 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.008236 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.003001 seconds.
```

but as I run the code in a m file, I get much accurate result. +/- 0.01ms

```
Elapsed time is 1.000032 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.000041 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.000021 seconds.
```

and the possible reason is:
If you run the code as m file, matlab try to pars the code in advance and your code will be run quicker and there is no intermediate parsing phase for each individual lines.

Comment: It's not so much that preparsing is quicker as that the order changes, and all the parsing is done before the call to `tic`, and therefore not measured by `toc`.

Answer (score 2):

I **suspect** this is due to the fact that the `sections` of code which are run when you select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> are already stored in memory so they are "ready to run", whereas when you press <kbd>F9</kbd> Matlab has to read whats selected from the editor after you press <kbd>F9</kbd>.